# How do I create my own pluggable session state provider

Tags: asp.net, session-state

I want to create my own session state provider, a pluggable one. I would like to know the following details for the same:

1. Is IIS required for this?
2. I donot want to use any database to store the session,then what should I use? (Can I use cache?)
3. Can anyone provide me with the architecture of how will this model look like? As in where will the custom session state provider fit in?

Any sample examples will be highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: With regards to your first question: are you not using IIS?

Comment: I'm totally new to all this,that is the reason why I have asked for an architectural representation of the components that are required for making/getting the custom session provider working.
I really don't know where will IIS fit into all this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`SessionStateStoreProviderBase`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.sessionstate.sessionstatestoreproviderbase.aspx) is the base class for storage. You can implement any kind of out-of-process storage, for instance file system based where you serialize the objects to a file on disk (kind of like PHP).

If you choose a storage strategy that somehow uses the web server cache then obviously your SessionStateStore will need to take a dependency on the web server, whether that is IIS or some other service depends on your environment. Windows Azure supports [cache for session storage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/gg457897).

[Session State Providers on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa478952.aspx) has more information and a code sample for a SQL Server provider.

Comment: Still I don't understand what role does IIS play into all this,I mean is IIS really needed in this?Can you please explain to me this too.
Moreover please can you also tell me what all is needed to write my own session state provider? Like what are the hardware/software components required?

Comment: It all depends on your implementation. If all you do is save state to disk, well then you would need enough disk space and read/write permissions. If you save state to the database, you obviously need a database. IIS is the most popular web server for running ASP.NET and is included in Windows. The web server is required for a session state provider if you save state in the web server.

Comment: Ok great..thanks a ton michielvoo ,this kind of solves my problem...I now have a better understanding of how I'm gonna implement my own session state provider,thanks.

Comment: No problem, don't forget to accept the answer (and vote if you like) 

[How does accepting an answer work](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)